# Site is abnormally slow

Tags: wordpress, image, performance

My site is running on Wordpress and uses Woocommerce to display most of the content. See my site [here](http://lostgrok.com), I have a lot of images that could be part of the problem...

Google PageSpeed says I'm 0/100 for mobile speed and 11/100 for desktop speed, with a 44.5 server response time..

GTmetrix gives me an F for my speed, recommending I serve scaled images, leverage browser caching, add expired headers, make fewer http requests, and more.

I'm trying to interpret all of these poor scores, and would like some help on how to dramatically speed up my site.

Does anyone have any tips, or know what I can do to help increase the speed and improve my scores on these sites?

Answer (score 0):

That site is certainly slow, however the load times appear to be primarily from the server (I'm seeing about a 3-5s load time before the server responds with content for the home page). This has nothing to do with how many images you are loading, it probably means you have a really slow plugin or piece of code.

I'm not sure how technical you are, but I'd recommend [profiling your code](http://brandonwamboldt.ca/optimizing-your-php-with-xdebug-1455/). An easier solution may be to disable your plugins one-by-one until your site suddenly loads faster. Then re-enable every plugin except the last one to be disabled, and verify your site still loads fast. If it does, then the disabled plugin is likely the issue.